React Native: Render error when trying to make text components draggable with gesture handling
I'm developing a photo editing feature in a React Native app where users can add text overlays that are draggable.
I'm using hooks to manage the text blocks positions and update them through gesture handling.
However, when I attempt to update the position of these text elements during a gesture (e.g., drag),
I encounter a render error: "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
I suspect the issue might be related to how hooks or gesture handlers are implemented. How can I correctly update the position of text blocks without running into this render error?
 {textBlocks.map((block, index) => (
                      <Text
                        onLayout={(event) => {
                          const { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                          setTextSize({ width, height });
                        }}
                        key={index}
                        style={[styles.addedTextStyle, { left: block.x, top: block.y, color: block.color, fontSize: fontSize, }]}>
                        {block.text}
                      </Text>
                    ))}


rn-draggable
rn-drag-text-editor
Chain reanimated + animated View
rn-gesture-handler (adding listeners for each text)

Methods which i tried to make text draggable after adding to screen.
Each of them leads to error.

Can you share exactly why it is not working? I tried making my text draggable and it works fine. I tried using rn-draggable and it works easily.
Can you share your code for more context?

How to send whole code ?
Too long to paste here.

The error you are facing is related to react hooks. You might have something in your code that is causing conditional rendering with fewer hooks. e.g.
const ComponentA = (listings) => {
    const {isLoading} = useSelector(state => state.app);

    if(isLoading){
        return <Loader>Loading...</Loader>
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       console.log("This could be any hook")
    }, [])

    return (<ComponentB>{Data}</ComponentB>)
}

Above snippet will cause one less/more useEffect hook before/after loading and will cause the same error as it exits the component because of the return statement for loading. To fix this we move the
if (isLoading) {
  return <Loader> Loading... </Loader>
}

after the useEffect hook. It should look something like this:
const ComponentA = (listings) => {
        const {isLoading} = useSelector(state => state.app);

        useEffect(() => {
           console.log("This could be any hook")
        }, [])

        if(isLoading){
            return <Loader>Loading...</Loader>
        }

        return (<ComponentB>{Data}</ComponentB>)
}


Thanks for answer. But i still get Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
when i try to add listeners for each element
